# Can I get a poor question I asked disassociated from my account? And if so how?

Tags: discussion, support, disassociation

I'll get straight to the point. I asked a very poor question a while ago; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38642958/why-are-pointers-used-in-c) one. I deleted the question, and have not tried to edit since, because I cannot fix it.  Its just in general, a bad question.

I've began to wonder if I could ask a Stack Exchange employee to disassociate the question from my account. I know that they probably get hundreds of request like this every day, and that I would probably get my request rejected. But I might as well try. I have read other post on Meta Stack Exchange that have asked for the same thing. But I thought my question might have a better chance at getting disassociated from my account because it has no answers, is down-voted, and adds no real, lasting value to the Stack Overflow community.

If this was a realistic idea, where exactly would I ask a Stack Exchange employee to disassociate a question from my account?

Comment: It was already fully deleted over a month ago -- so why worry about it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  Because it counts against them, would be my guess.

Comment: Honestly I'm kind of torn on this issue, since we don't really want people to flagrantly abuse this sort of thing should it exist to circumvent limits and bans, but I'm not necessarily opposed to the notion of a mulligan for accounts that are otherwise in good form.

Comment: @Makoto exactly. That is my reason.

Comment: @makoto in the end, regardless of feelings, there is zero option. SE must disassociate upon request since it is a requirement of the license. However, I recall reading that the community team does have options to prevent abuse of this to constantly avoid a q-Ban. I am assuming account deletion is a last resort option.

Comment: @Makoto I  went ahead and just contacted the Stack Exchange team. That was eight hours ago. How long does the process general take? And what do they mean by, _well contact your shortly_? do they mean by e-mail? I apologize for asking this in the comments, but this was something I was going do add to my question before it as closed.

Comment: It's a weekend, give it some time.

Comment: @ivarni Oh no. I know it's a weekend( not to mention it's labor day weekend). It may have came across as if I was being impatient, but I was just wondering if Makto knew how long it general takes, during buisness hours of course, and how exactly they will contact you.